# LogCat on ADT Eclipse doesnot work

Tags: android

I am using ADT on Eclipse but the LogCat view does not show any messages when debugging on a device even though I use this

```
Log.d("tag","msg");
```

through out my code. It only shows a warning:

```
 Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dial this: ***#*#2846579#*#*** 
Service menu will appear.

Go to `"ProjectMenu" -> "Background Setting" -> "Log Setting"`

Open `"Log switch"` and set it to **ON**.

Open `"Log level setting"` and set the log level you wish.

Reboot the phone.
[sample](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/155/logcat-doesnt-show-messages-error-unable-to-open-log-device/)

Answer (score 1):

In your your `Manifest` file, update `application` XML by setting `android:debuggable` attribute to `true`

```
<application
         ......

         android:debuggable="true" >

  ......

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have android:debuggable="true" in your AndroidManifest??

Comment: No i dont. where do i place it?

Comment: in application tag like this : <application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon".../>

Answer (score 0):

use the following

```
Log.v("tag","msg");
```

then see, it shows in logcat